# Using `optim()` for MLE estimates with dynamic distributional assumptions

Tags: r, optimization, mle, log-likelihood

We can write a simple function that generates a random variable according to any user-specified distribution, including those with a varying number of distributional parameters:

```
random_variates <- function(n, distribution, ...){
  distribution(n, ...)
}

set.seed(123)

# negative binomial, 2 parameters
random_variates(n = 5, distribution = rnbinom, mu = 5, size = 0.5)
# [1]  1  3  0 34  3

# Poisson, 1 parameter
random_variates(n = 5, distribution = rpois, lambda = 5)
# [1] 9 8 6 7 1
```

Conversely, we can also write a function that uses `optim()` to estimate maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters given the data, but for each distribution there must be a distribution-specific log likelihood function:

```
# Log likelihood function for Negative Binomial
nb_ll <- function(params, data){
  -sum(log(dnbinom(data, mu = params[1], size = params[2])))
}

# example data
z_vals <- c(5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
            3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0)

#MLE estimates
optim(c(0.01, 0.01), nb_ll, data = z_vals)[["par"]]
# [1] 0.973937 0.476989
```

I would like to combine these two ideas and write a likelihood function that can be passed through `optim()` and allows the user to specify the distribution, without the need for distribution-specific likelihood functions. Something like:

```
# this of course doesn't work

any_ll <- function(params, distribution, data, ...){
  -sum(log(distribution(data, ...)))
}
optim(c(0.01), any_ll, data = z_vals, distribution = dpois)
optim(c(0.01, 0.01), any_ll, data = z_vals, distribution = dnbinom)
```

Is there any way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that can be considered

```
z_vals <- c(5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
            3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0)

any_ll <- function(params, FUN, data)
{
  text <- paste0("-sum(log(FUN(data", paste0(",", params, collapse = ""), ")))")
  eval(parse(text = text))
}

optim(c(0.01), any_ll, data = z_vals, FUN = dpois)

$par
[1] 0.9735

$value
[1] 60.83354

$counts
function gradient 
      40       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

optim(c(1, 1), any_ll, data = z_vals, FUN = dgamma)

$par
[1] 1.000000 1.027027

$value
[1] 36.98661

$counts
function gradient 
     181       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Wonderful idea! A great start - the only remaining issue is when a distribution can have multiple parameterizations. For instance, `dnbinom(z_vals, prob = 0.5, size = 0.5)` or  `dnbinom(z_vals, mu = 0.5, size = 0.5)` and how to specify the parameterization (at the moment it returns the wrong estimate in this instance because it assumed `probs = xx` when I need `mu = xx`. But this is a brilliant approach to build off of- thank you!

Comment: By default, the params are in orders. For example, we have dgamma(x, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, log = FALSE). So, the first parameter of the dgamma function is the shape paramter and the second is the rate by default with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the arguments of a fonction with "formalArgs". Hence, we can get the parameter names with the following code :

```
sol_Par <- c(1.000000, 1.027027)
arg_Names <- formalArgs(dgamma)
arg_Names <- arg_Names[-1]
arg_Names[1 : length(sol_Par)]
 "shape" "rate"
```

Also, you can consider the following approach :

```
z_vals <- c(5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0,
            3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0)

z_vals[z_vals == 0] <- 1

any_ll <- function(params, FUN, data)
{
  params_Name <- names(params)
  text <- paste0("-sum(log(FUN(data", paste0(",", params_Name, "=", params, collapse = ""), ")))")
  eval(parse(text = text))
}

par_Init_Pois <- c("lambda" = 0.01)
optim(par_Init_Pois, any_ll, data = z_vals, FUN = dpois)

par_Init_Gamma <- c("shape" = 1, "rate" = 100)
optim(par_Init_Gamma, any_ll, data = z_vals, FUN = dgamma)
```

With this approach, you can specify the name of the parameters you want to optimize on by specifying their names in the vectors "par_Init_Pois" and "par_Init_Gamma".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to slightly modify Emmanuel Hamel's brilliant idea to have the user specify the parameters in the function itself:

```
z_vals <- c(5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 
            3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0)

any_ll <- function(params, FUN, data, user_params){
  fmlargs <- formalArgs(FUN)
  userargs <- paste(paste(fmlargs[fmlargs %in% user_params], separate = " = "),
                   params, collapse = ", ")
  text <- paste0("-sum(log(FUN(data, ", userargs, ")))") 
  eval(parse(text = text))
}

nb_ll <- function(params, data){
  -sum(log(dnbinom(data, mu = params[1], size = params[2])))
}

# NB
optim(c(0.01, 0.01), any_ll, data = z_vals, FUN = dnbinom, user_params = c("mu", "size"))

#Poi
optim(0.01, any_ll, data = z_vals, FUN = dpois, user_params = "lambda")
```